# MySQL concurrent LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: c++, mysql, c, linux, mariadb

I've got a small sample set of data - nine files, 1,000,000 lines in each file. The real data is all captured in real time and later inserted into a MySQL database. The first time I tried this, it took just over 16 hours to insert the total data set (~500 million lines, 24GB plain text). I figured that's too slow, so went about trying to speed it up.

To that end, I've got a fully functional multithreaded implementation of a program I've been working on for a while. For each file, it'll create a table, create a temporary file with the appropriate SQL, and then run a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` on each of those files.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
void insert_data(uint32_t tid)
{
  string scribe_file;

  file_list_mutex.lock();
  while(scribe_files.size() > 0)
  {
    scribe_file = *(scribe_files.begin());
    scribe_files.erase(scribe_files.begin());
    file_list_mutex.unlock();

    MYSQL *thread_con = mysql_init(nullptr);

    if(thread_con == nullptr)
    {
      log_mutex.lock();
      cerr << "Thead " << tid << ": " << mysql_error(thread_con) << endl;
      log_mutex.unlock();
      return;
    }

    if(nullptr == (mysql_real_connect(thread_con, server.c_str(), user.c_str(),
                                      password.c_str(), nullptr,
                                      0, nullptr, 0)))
    {
      log_mutex.lock();
      cerr << "Thead " << tid << ": " << mysql_error(thread_con) << endl;
      log_mutex.unlock();
      mysql_close(thread_con);
      return;
    }

    if(mysql_select_db(thread_con, database.c_str()))
    {
      log_mutex.lock();
      cerr << "Thead " << tid << ": " << mysql_error(thread_con) << endl;
      log_mutex.unlock();
      mysql_close(thread_con);
      return;
    }

    string table_name = get_table_name(scribe_file);

    if(table_name.empty())
    {
      log_mutex.lock();
      cerr << "Thead " << tid << ": Unusuable input file: " << scribe_file << endl;
      log_mutex.unlock();
      return;
    }

    ifstream scribe_stream(scribe_file);

    if(!scribe_stream.good())
    {
      log_mutex.lock();
      cerr << "Thead " << tid << ": Error opening " << scribe_file << endl;
      log_mutex.unlock();
      return;
    }

    string output_filename = "/tmp/";
    {
      vector<string> file_path = split_string(scribe_file, '/');
      output_filename.append(file_path.rbegin()[0]);
    }
    output_filename.append(".sql");

    ofstream output;
    output.open(output_filename, ios::out | ios::trunc);

    if(!output.good())
    {
      log_mutex.lock();
      cerr << "Thead " << tid << ": Error opening " << output_filename << endl;
      log_mutex.unlock();
      scribe_stream.close();
      return;
    }

    string create_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ";

    string table_format = " (IDpk INT NOT NULL auto_increment,"
                          " s CHAR(8) NOT NULL,"
                          " si INT unsigned NOT NULL,"
                          " pq TINYINT unsigned NOT NULL,"
                          " pr BIGINT unsigned DEFAULT NULL,"
                          " sz INT DEFAULT NULL,"
                          " io TINYINT unsigned DEFAULT NULL,"
                          " ipslt TINYINT unsigned DEFAULT NULL,"
                          " is TINYINT unsigned DEFAULT NULL,"
                          " ilp BIGINT unsigned DEFAULT NULL,"
                          " ips INT unsigned DEFAULT NULL,"
                          " at INT unsigned DEFAULT NULL,"
                          " vn TINYINT unsigned NOT NULL,"
                          " ms BIGINT unsigned NOT NULL,"
                          " us BIGINT unsigned NOT NULL,"
                          " PRIMARY KEY(IDpk),"
                          " KEY(us),"
                          " KEY(s),"
                          " KEY(pq))";

    create_query.append(table_name);
    create_query.append(table_format);

    if(mysql_query(thread_con, create_query.c_str()))
    {
      log_mutex.lock();
      cerr << "Thead " << tid << ": " << mysql_error(thread_con) << endl;
      log_mutex.unlock();

      scribe_stream.close();
      output.close();
      mysql_close(thread_con);
      return;
    }

    string scribe_stream_line;
    char values[MAX_TOKENS * MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH];
    usec_t start_time = get_current_us_time();
    uint64_t num_lines = 0;

    log_mutex.lock();
    cout << "Thread " << tid << ": Starting " << scribe_file << endl;
    log_mutex.unlock();

    char scribe_tokens[MAX_TOKENS][MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH];

    while(getline(scribe_stream, scribe_stream_line))
    {
      split_scribe_line(scribe_stream_line, scribe_tokens);
      num_lines++;

      if(scribe_tokens[6][0] != '\0')
      {
        try
        {
          uint32_t item_type = stoi(scribe_tokens[2]);
          fill(values, values + (MAX_TOKENS * MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH), '\0');

          switch(item_type)
          {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            {
              sprintf(values,
                        "%s,%s,%s,"
                        "%s,%s,"
                        "NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"
                        "%s,%s,%s",
                        scribe_tokens[0], scribe_tokens[1], scribe_tokens[2],
                        scribe_tokens[3], scribe_tokens[4], scribe_tokens[5],
                        scribe_tokens[6], scribe_tokens[7]);
              break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
              sprintf(values,
                        "%s,%s,%s,"
                        "%s,%s,%s,%s,"
                        "NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"
                        "%s,%s,%s",
                        scribe_tokens[0], scribe_tokens[1], scribe_tokens[2],
                        scribe_tokens[3], scribe_tokens[4], scribe_tokens[5],
                        scribe_tokens[6], scribe_tokens[7], scribe_tokens[8],
                        scribe_tokens[9]);
              break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
              sprintf(values,
                        "%s,%s,%s,"
                        "NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"
                        "NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"
                        "%s,%s,%s",
                        scribe_tokens[0], scribe_tokens[1], scribe_tokens[2],
                        scribe_tokens[3], scribe_tokens[4], scribe_tokens[5]);
              break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
              sprintf(values,
                        "%s,%s,%s,"
                        "%s,%s,NULL,NULL,"
                        "%s,%s,%s,NULL,"
                        "%s,%s,%s",
                        scribe_tokens[0], scribe_tokens[1], scribe_tokens[2],
                        scribe_tokens[3], scribe_tokens[4], scribe_tokens[5],
                        scribe_tokens[6], scribe_tokens[7], scribe_tokens[8],
                        scribe_tokens[9], scribe_tokens[10]);
              break;
            }
            case 5:
            {
              sprintf(values,
                        "%s,%s,%s,"
                        "NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"
                        "%s,%s,%s,%s",
                        scribe_tokens[0], scribe_tokens[1], scribe_tokens[2],
                        scribe_tokens[3], scribe_tokens[4], scribe_tokens[5],
                        scribe_tokens[6]);
              break;
            }

            default:
              log_mutex.lock();
              cerr << "Thread " << tid << ": Unknown pq type " << item_type << "\n"
                   << "    " << scribe_stream_line << endl;
              log_mutex.lock();
              continue;
              break;
          }

          output << values << endl;
        }
        catch(exception &ex)
        {
          log_mutex.lock();
          cerr << "Thread " << tid << ": Error parsing scribe line\n  '"
               << scribe_stream_line << "'\n" << "  " << ex.what() << endl;
          log_mutex.unlock();

          scribe_stream.close();
          output.close();

          throw;
        }
      }
    }

    log_mutex.lock();
    cout << "Thread " << tid << ": preparing " << num_lines << " lines took "
         << us_to_hhmmss(get_current_us_time() - start_time) << endl;
    log_mutex.unlock();

    string insert_query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ";
    insert_query.append("'" + output_filename + "' INTO TABLE "
                        + table_name + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','");

    log_mutex.lock();
    cout << "Thread " << tid << ": Loading results into database." << endl;
    log_mutex.unlock();

    start_time = get_current_us_time();

    if(mysql_query(thread_con, insert_query.c_str()))
    {
      log_mutex.lock();
      cerr << "Thead " << tid << ": " <<mysql_error(thread_con) << endl;
      log_mutex.unlock();

      scribe_stream.close();
      output.close();
      mysql_close(thread_con);
      return;
    }

    mysql_close(thread_con);

    log_mutex.lock();
    cout << "Thread " << tid << ": " << "Insertion took "
         << us_to_hhmmss(get_current_us_time() - start_time) << endl;
    log_mutex.unlock();

    scribe_stream.close();
    output.close();
    remove(output_filename.c_str());
  }
  file_list_mutex.unlock();
}
```

The thing that's really giving away my lack of understanding is performance inconsistency. For instance, when I ran it with two files with one and two threads, performance was about equivalent:

```
Scribe DB CLI V1.07
Got 8 CPU cores.
Parsing 2 input files.
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_1.data
Thread 1: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_0.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:02
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 1: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:02
Thread 1: Loading results into database.
Thread 1: Insertion took 00:00:35
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:00:37
Total runtime: 00:00:40

Scribe DB CLI V1.07
Got 1 CPU cores.
Parsing 2 input files.
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_0.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:00:19
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_1.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:00:20
Total runtime: 00:00:43
```

I dropped the database each time I ran this test.

Similarly, when running on all 9 input files, I've had varied results, but nothing indicating a proper speedup:

```
Scribe DB CLI V1.07
Got 1 CPU cores.
Parsing 9 input files.
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_0.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:00:19
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_1.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:00:20
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_2.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:00:20
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_3.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:00:21
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_4.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:00:21
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_5.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:00:21
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_6.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:00:21
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_7.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:00:21
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_8.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:00:21
Total runtime: 00:03:27

Scribe DB CLI V1.07
Got 8 CPU cores.
Parsing 9 input files.
Thread 3: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_3.data
Thread 1: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_4.data
Thread 2: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_1.data
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_0.data
Thread 4: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_2.data
Thread 5: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_5.data
Thread 3: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:03
Thread 3: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:03
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 2: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:03
Thread 2: Loading results into database.
Thread 4: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:03
Thread 4: Loading results into database.
Thread 1: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:03
Thread 1: Loading results into database.
Thread 5: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:03
Thread 5: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:02:20
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_6.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 1: Insertion took 00:02:44
Thread 1: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_7.data
Thread 1: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 1: Loading results into database.
Thread 5: Insertion took 00:03:01
Thread 5: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_8.data
Thread 5: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 5: Loading results into database.
Thread 3: Insertion took 00:03:07
Thread 4: Insertion took 00:03:10
Thread 2: Insertion took 00:03:14
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:01:37
Thread 1: Insertion took 00:01:20
Thread 5: Insertion took 00:01:06
Total runtime: 00:04:14

Scribe DB CLI V1.08
Got 8 CPU cores.
Parsing 9 input files.
Thread 5: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_4.data
Thread 1: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_1.data
Thread 3: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_2.data
Thread 4: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_5.data
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_0.data
Thread 2: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_3.data
Thread 5: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:03
Thread 5: Loading results into database.
Thread 4: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:03
Thread 4: Loading results into database.
Thread 1: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:03
Thread 1: Loading results into database.
Thread 3: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:03
Thread 3: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:03
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 2: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:03
Thread 2: Loading results into database.
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:01:43
Thread 0: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_6.data
Thread 0: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 0: Loading results into database.
Thread 5: Insertion took 00:02:00
Thread 5: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_7.data
Thread 5: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 5: Loading results into database.
Thread 2: Insertion took 00:02:02
Thread 2: Starting scribe_20170511/short_scribe_8.data
Thread 4: Insertion took 00:02:04
Thread 3: Insertion took 00:02:04
Thread 2: preparing 1000000 lines took 00:00:01
Thread 2: Loading results into database.
Thread 1: Insertion took 00:02:06
Thread 0: Insertion took 00:00:59
Thread 5: Insertion took 00:00:49
Thread 2: Insertion took 00:00:48
Total runtime: 00:02:57
```

What am I looking at here? I see 10-50% CPU utilization on my 8 core during the queries as well as 15-40mb/s disk utilization on my SSD. I'm sure there's some complicated caching and other such fancy work behind the scenes that explains the inconsistency, but I really expected separate tables to yield a better performance bump.

Thanks in advance. =)

#### EDIT:

Adding details for [Rick James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766831/rick-james):

- Host OS: Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)
- Host RAM: 16GB
- Host SQL Engine: InnoDB

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                       | Value          |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size             | 8388608        |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size       | 134217728      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct         | 25             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances        | 1              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 134217728      |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size       | 25             |
| innodb_change_buffering             | all            |
| innodb_log_buffer_size              | 16777216       |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size             | 1048576        |
| join_buffer_size                    | 262144         |
| key_buffer_size                     | 16777216       |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size             | 8388608        |
| net_buffer_length                   | 16384          |
| preload_buffer_size                 | 32768          |
| read_buffer_size                    | 131072         |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                | 262144         |
| sort_buffer_size                    | 262144         |
| sql_buffer_result                   | OFF            |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't have plans to combine the tables. The reason I don't insert them as they become available (other than that a single file takes longer to insert than it does to record the next one) is that there's work done on the files on the server they're created on during the day. And finally, I do need at least the first two indices, because there need to sensible queries based on those two columns.

Comment: I'm not sure how much of an improvement you'll see unless you increase the resources to the server; inserting and indexing data takes time.

Comment: I was hoping "resources" might, in this case, be something configurable. It's got 16GB RAM and two 3Ghz, quad core Xeons. It's all quite old, but still arguably serviceable. I suppose I expected to see eight MySQL threads at 80% CPU utilization or something. Alas, that was not the case.

Comment: Which `ENGINE`?  Don't include secondary indexes, only the PK.  Will you be combining the 1M tables together?  If so, how?  Why do in parallel instead of doing them as they become available?  Are you running in Windows?  Or *nix?  How much RAM?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';`  (After those answers, I may have more questions; maybe some advice.)

Comment: Added answers to your questions. Oddly, I had been increasing the buffer size (`innodb_buffer_pool_size=10737418240` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) but it doesn't appear to have taken hold...